# Line integral over vector field $F(x,y) = (\sin(x) + 3x^2,2x-e^{-y^{2}})$

Tags: integration

I have to calculate line integral over vector field $F(x,y) = (\sin(x) + 3x^2,2x-e^{-y^{2}})$.

The path is the unit circle edge, from (1,0) to (-1,0).

So I have $\gamma_{1}(t)=\{(\cos(t),\sin(t)|0\leq t \leq \pi \}$ and

$\gamma_{2}(t)=\{(t,0)| -1\leq t \leq 1 \}$.

Now this area enclosed by these two curves is $A$ and it's $m(A)=\pi / 2$.

So I have calculated $D_{1}f_{2}= 2$ and $D_{2}f_{1}=6y$.

So now I have

$\pi / 2 = \int_{\partial A} f_{1}dx+f_{2}dy=\int_{\gamma_{1}} f_{1}dx+f_{2}dy + \int_{\gamma_{2}} f_{1}dx+f_{2}dy $ and I know that $\int_{\gamma_{2}} f_{1}dx+f_{2}dy = 4$, since I used the partial derivatives above and the $\gamma_{2}$.

So according to this I get that the $\int_{\gamma_{1}} f_{1}dx + f_{2}dy$

is $\pi/2 -4$.

Put, apparently, I am wrong and the correct answer is $\pi -4$ and I do not have a clue where did go wrong!

Comment: You claim that the integral over the boundary of $A$ is $\pi/2$. Why is that? Why do you claim it should be the area? I guess, without having done any calculations, that this is not correct, and that you will find your error there.

Answer (score 1):

The area of the enclosed region is not enough. You have to integrate $D_1f_2-D_2f_1$ over the semicircle. Integrating 2 gives $2\cdot \pi/2=\pi$, while integrating $6y$ should give 4. And it is:

$\int_m 6y=\int_0^1 6y\cdot 2\sqrt{1-y^2}\mathrm{d}y=4$

after the substitution $t=1-y^2$.

Comment: Thank you. I now see my error.